# Вызов C++ DLL с маршалированием на C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Прошу помощи, т. к. столкнулся с проблемой вызова DLL (не .NET).
Есть библиотека "AwUsbApi.dll" с 4-мя функциями доступными для вызова, приведу пример на одной из них "AwUsbConnect"

**Ее вызов для C++**

```
 __declspec(dllexport)
    AWUSB_STATUS
    _cdecl
    AwUsbConnect (
        IN  LPCWSTR         Hub,    
        IN  PAWUSB_STATUS   Status,
        IN  DWORD           Timeout,
        IN  HANDLE          hEvent OPTIONAL
    );
```

**Мой вызов ее на С#:**

```
    [DllImport("AwUsbApi.dll", EntryPoint = "AwUsbConnect", 
        CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int AwConnect(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string IP, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder Status, 
        int TimeOut);
```

Но, к сожалению, это не работает, статусы меняются, но реального воздействия на физическое устройство не происходит =(

Ниже описание функции:

- AwUsbConnect
- Parms:
- Hub
- [in] AwUsb Hub IP Address in string format. (e.g. "192.168.1.10:3" 
          for
- host 192.168.1.10 and group 3).
- Status
- [out] Updated upon return from function, and, when hEvent is non-
          NULL,
- after the connect operation completes. See Return Values.
- Timeout
- [in] Specifies how long to wait for connection to succeed, in 
           milliseconds.
- Must be non-zero. Set value to INFINITE in order to wait forever.
- Returns AWUSB_STATUS_TIMEOUT if timeout interval elapses.
- hEvent
- [in] Handle to an event which will be set to the signaled state when 
          the
- operation has been completed. If hEvent is NULL, this function will
- block until it completes. If hEvent is non-NULL, then the function
- returns immediately, usually with AWUSB_STATUS_PENDING unless an 
          error
- has occurred.  To create an event object, use the CreateEvent 
          function.
- An application must wait until hEvent has been signaled before 
          calling
- CloseHandle.

Comment: Не забывайте о красоте русского языка ;) К тому же, чтобы обозначить код, *выделите его весь*.

Comment: К сожалению, я лишь *администрировал* Ваш вопрос. Не беспокойтесь, через несколько минут Вам ответят.

Comment: А SetLastError не пробовали посмотреть ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror.aspx

Comment: Пробовал, но он мне ни чего не дал, вернул 0 и все, но все равно спасибо!